# Applicability of the continuity equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

In systems such as the following;
[image]

Applying Bernoulli's equation to the mouth of the tube and to 
 the point just below the rightmost column, you get an excess pressure head on the energy sum of the latter.
Obviously, fluid velocity is not constant across the tube. But using the continuity equation, we get the velocities to be equal because the areas are also equal.

How is that possible? Isn't continuity applicable there?

Comment: Assuming the fluid is incompressible then volumetric throughput, and thus fluid velocity, MUST be constant. The continuity equation holds.

Comment: The diagram is NOT for an inviscid fluid.

Comment: Isn't the Bernoulli's equation right, then?

Comment: BE is for inviscid fluids only. It does not account for viscous losses. The drop in pressure you see in the diagram is due to viscous losses.

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pressure drops indicate that the fluid loses some energy as it flows into the pipe due to its viscosity and/or to friction on the pipe boundary. The pressure drop indeed violates Bernouilli's equation, which is a statement of the flow energy conservation.